# Sync ADFS Claims without relogin

Tags: asp.net, adfs2.0, component-space

I'm using [ComponentSpace](https://www.componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net) for ADFS SSO and it works perfectly fine to Sync users on login, but is there a way to Sync user properties/roles in background, i.e. user shouldn't have to relogin for Updated Claims to Sync with the Service Provider. Thanks for your help and suggestions. I see few stackoverflow Questions where they say it is not possible, but some of them are quite old. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no, this is not possible.

Claims are not dynamic and there is no SAML flow to asynchronously update the claims.

Comment: Is it possible to sync users roles and attributes without AD FS Claims in background? While using AD FS for authentication. I couldn't find an official documentation where it says that I cannot sync user attributes.

Comment: You would have to access AD via the C# LDAP routines and then convert the result into claims.